# Finding the first, second and third maxima in the plot

Tags: matlab, filtering

I want to find the first, second and third peaks in the data set that I have plotted using MATLAB. Can someone help me with this? Here is the link to the plot that I have uploaded

[image]

The central idea is to find peaks which occur after certain time interval. The second condition is just to store the first four peaks and then break the condition. So I find the first maxima value in the graph. I see the time value which is 2530 on X-axis. I then do not look in the immediate neighbourhood but look for a peak which comes after 180-200 on X-axis. I get peak 2 which is then stored . Then again I jump by 180-200 and again search for peaks in the neighbourhood. Finally after getting the first four maximas I stop searching for peaks

Comment: Start by defining a maxima. There are a couple of local maxima that are bigger then your second circled point

Comment: @Rasman i know there are more maximas but I need only those peaks which I have marked. I also found from the graph that if my first waveform peak is at lets say 2530 then my next peak of the waveform will be at approximately 180-200 milliseconds after the first waveform peak. So my next peak will be something in between 2710 and 2730.

Comment: then why isn't there a peak at 3350?

Comment: @rasman that is why my area of interest is finding the first four peaks which are marked. They represent a sound signal from sensor, and the signal is attenuating. As soom as I get the fourth peak I have to stop code execution.

Comment: rewrite your question more explicitly then. Make it clear what you're looking for it as it changes the algorithm needed to perform your analysis

Comment: Sorry if the question is not clear. The central idea is to find peaks which occur after certain time interval. The second condition is just to store the first four peaks and then break the condition. So I find the first maxima value in the graph. I see the time value which is 2530 on X-axis. I then do not look in the immediate neighbourhood but look for a peak which comes after 180-200 on X-axis. I get peak 2 which is then stored . Then again I jump by 180-200 and again search for peaks in the neighbourhood. Finally after getting the first four maximas i stop searching for peaks.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do in these cases is search for the maximum, then erase all points in a small neighborhood around that maximum point and repeat the processes. The neighborhood size is, of course, application dependent.

So if you have the data in vector `y`, the following should work:

```
 [max1, max_ind] = max(y);
 y(max_ind-delta:max_ind+delta) = 0;

 [max2, max_ind2] = max(y);
```

Comment: The problem with the solution given above is suppose I have a value which is not a marked peak in my figure but it is maximum of the max_ind-delta and max_ind+delta. So this value also gets saved, but actually it has to be neglected.

Comment: @maverick: Once you find a primary peak at `max_ind`, this code will then erase any secondary peaks in the surrounding window. You should not be saving any neighboring peaks.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to nimrodm's answer, you can use your known time delay to your advantage.  Find your first maximum, then jump ahead your known delay and search for a max within a smaller window.  You'll have to adjust the index when doing this, but works great.

With data in vector `y`:

```
[max1,max_ind1] = max(y);
next_ind = max_ind + 190;

[max2,max_ind2] = max(y(next_ind-20:next_ind+20));
max_ind2 = max_ind2 + next_ind-21;
```

Comment: Yes David the above code works fine in the above case but there are some waveforms where I have just one single peak, so actually I should stop exection there and just store one value.

Comment: @maverick You would have that problem with nimrodm's solution as well. For either case you could set a threshold, and if you find no peaks above the threshold, then stop looking.

Answer (score 0):

The [findpeaks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) function will give you all the peaks in the vector, but it need do more works to filter the peaks which you don't care. A low pass filter might be applied before `findpeaks` to do that.